# Paste event listener on Internet Explorer getting wrong arguments

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, clipboard, internet-explorer-11

I'm handling the paste events for a `contenteditable` to clean all HTML markers before paste. All Works fine in `Firefox` and `Chrome`. But when I test my code in `IE11`, the `event object` passed is not a `ClipboardEvent` but a `DragEvent`.

Is there something wrong with my code?
If I add the listener as the code bellow, should I get the clipboard event. Why I'm getting drag?

```
editable.addEventListener('paste', pasteHandler, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vepo/4t2ofv8n/

To test the example above, I'm copy a text from Chrome and paste into IE. But I you copy any text from IE will get the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617938/angular2-component-with-clipboarddata-property

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var editable = document.getElementById('editable-div');
    var pasteHandler = function(e){
        if(e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
            var pastedText = "";
            if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
                pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
                pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
            }

            alert(pastedText);
        }
        else{
            alert('Not paste object!');
        }
    };
    editable.addEventListener('paste', pasteHandler, false);
});
```

here I handle the IE Version and the other browsers as well.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr4src83/)

Comment: HTMLDivElement doesn't support `attachEvent`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868700.aspx

Comment: @Victor check the edit it is a new approach to your problem, the handler is fine it was the way you get your clipboard cach that wasn't right.

Answer (score 11):

`e.clipboardData` was always null for me on IE, so I came up with this:

```
var pastedText = '';
if (typeof e.clipboardData === 'undefined')
    pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
else
    pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
```

Answer (score 4):

`e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')` works for safari, chrome, firefox and safari and chrome on an Ipad.

`window.clipboardData.getData('text')` works for Internet Explorer and Edge.

Note: `e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text')`  works for desktop browsers but not for mobile browsers.

So in the end I used this

```
var clipText;
  if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData !== undefined){
    clipText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
  } else {
    clipText = window.clipboardData.getData('text')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("element").on('paste', function (e)
{
if (window.clipboardData) 
{
pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
}
else if (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData != undefined)
{
pastedText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
}
}
});
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain bit more about your answer and the issue in the question rather than just pasting a code

Comment: @sherein the code you've given looks like jquery that wasn't in the tag list of the question. If you introduce new libraries in your answer, you should at least explain how and why.