# Angular2 component with clipboardData property

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 component with a method to paste data from the clipboard:

```
inputPaste(event){
  let clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
  ...
```

}

This way doesn't work for IE10+, but IE have a window object with a property clipboardData, but typescript compilator throws an error:

```
inputPaste(event){
  let clipboardData = event.clipboardData 
            || window.clipboardData; //error 'clipboardData' does not exist on type Windows
  ...
```

}

I have found a solution, that we must use angular2-clipboard directive, but I wan't to use it.

How can I use `'windows.clipboardData'` in typescript?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
inputPaste(event){
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData 
                        || (<any>window).clipboardData; //typecasting to any
                        or
                        || window['clipboardData']; //access like to array
    ...
}
```

Comment: You may also use `(window as any).clipboardData`

Answer (score 0):

We can use navigator to get the clipboard data

```
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(s => console.log(s));
```